AWS Sending SNS mail with EventBrige when RDS failover (Terraform)
I wand to send mail notification with EventBridge & SNS.
So i wrote this code with Terraform.
But this code does not send mail.
resource "aws_sns_topic" "main" {
  name = "main"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "main" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.main.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "MY-EMAIL@SAMPLE.com"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "main" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.main.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.main.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "main" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["SNS:Publish"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.main.arn]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "main" {
  name        = "main"
  description = "RDS failover"
  
  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source = ["aws.rds"],
    detail_type = ["RDS DB Instance Event"],
    detail = {
      EventCategories = ["failover"]
    }
  })
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "main" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.main.name
  arn  = aws_sns_topic.main.arn
}

when i use only "aws_db_event_subscription" like this code, aws sends failover notification mail successfully.
resource "aws_sns_topic" "main" {
  name = "main"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "main" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.main.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "MY-EMAIL@SAMPLE.com"
}

resource "aws_db_event_subscription" "main" {
  name      = "main"
  sns_topic = aws_sns_topic.main.arn

  source_type = "db-instance"
  source_ids  = [aws_db_instance.main.identifier]

  event_categories = ["failover"]
}

What's the problem with my EventBridge side's code?
when i check on Cloudtrail, log says "FailedInvocations" (but there is no error code on Cloudtrail)
